# ErrorDocument and error 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

htaccess I have such a code

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.xxx.com/410.html
```

It redirects to the 410.php page with error 302

And I want to be redirected to this page with error 301

same file 410.php

```
header ("HTTP/1.0 410 Gone");
The requested page has been removed.
```

How do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't want  to be redirected at all: you just want that page to come up with the original error code, don't you? (ie. 404 or 410)

That can be achieved by using a relative path instead of a full URL:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /410.html
```